# PG::ForeignKeyViolation in Rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a model that is polymorphic in 2 ways:

```
class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :orderable, polymorphic: true, optional: true
end

class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :order_items, dependent: :destroy, as: :order
  has_many :orderables, through: :order_items, source: :orderable, source_type: 'Meal'
end

class FoodOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :order_items, dependent: :destroy, as: :order
    has_many :orderables, through: :order_items, source: :orderable, source_type: "Product"
end

class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord {
                :id => :integer,
          :order_id => :integer,
        :order_type => :string,
          :quantity => :integer,
        :created_at => :datetime,
        :updated_at => :datetime,
      :orderable_id => :integer,
    :orderable_type => :string
}
```

I am trying to create a new record in an Rspec test but it keeps giving me a `PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR`:

```
food_order = FoodOrder.create(name: "a")
product = Product.create(name: "b")
OrderItem.create(order_type: "FoodOrder", order_id: food_order.id, orderable_id: @product.id, orderable_type: "Product", quantity: 5)

ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey:
       PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "order_items" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_e3cb28f071"
       DETAIL:  Key (order_id)=(1) is not present in table "orders".
       : INSERT INTO "order_items" ("order_id", "quantity", "created_at", "updated_at", "orderable_id", "orderable_type", "order_type") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"
```

Despite the fact that I set `order_type: "FoodOrder"`, I'm getting an error because its searching the `orders` table when it should be searching the `food_orders` table.

How can I get around this?  Worth noting this error **does not** occur outside testing.

Comment: I would make a guess that in the migration file to create `OrderItem` you only have `t.belongs_to :orders` and forgot to specify the `polymophic: true` as hash option

Comment: @Thang doesn't that only impact the model?  I didn't think it modified the table in any way

Comment: You get *Postgresql* error, so you have to inspect DB structure, not model one. It seems that @Thang is absolutely right.

Comment: Ok, I still don't know how come it is working outside the testing. But if you only specify `t.belongs_to :orders, foreign_key: true` or `t.references :orders...` it will create an `order_items` table with a foreign_key column point to `orders` table (instead of a polymorphic foreign_key as expected)

Comment: The `schema.db` file showed an index on `order_id` which I just removed but the error still exists.

Comment: @Thang you were right!  There was a `foreign_key` created in a seperate migration which is why it slipped by!  Idk if you can make this a formal answer but I'll happily accept it.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyThomas, glad I can help. Mine is not even a proper answer, it's just a guess. You do all the debug yourself thought